# Error in the Crystal Reports Formula : The remaining text does not appear to be a part of the formula

Tags: crystal-reports

Following is the Crystal reports formula that I am using in one of my reports :

```
dim sDate as string

if({orderName;1.FAActiveOrder}  > 0) then 
 sDate = totext(CDateTime(CHTimeZoneCHDTTMConverterConvertDTTM ("CLIENT", Cstr({orderName;1.FAAuthorizedDTTM}),{?ClientSTDTZ} ,{?ServerSTDTZ} )),"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mmtt")
else ''
end if

if({orderName;1.FAActiveOrder}  > 0) then
formula = "The Order is placed by :" + ({orderName;1.FAAuthorizingP}) + " " + ({orderName;1.FAActivePCreds}) + " " + sDate
else ''

end if
```

Executing this formula is throwing me 'The remaining text does not appear to be a part of the formula' error. I cannot understand why? Can someone please help me correct this formula? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That expression relies on a User Function Library.
Install that UFL on this machine.